# Julia: How to iterate with Channel

Tags: julia

When I run the following code, I get a deprecation saying produce has been replace with channels.

```
function source(dir)
    filelist = readdir(dir)

    for filename in filelist
        name,ext = splitext(filename)
        if ext == ".jld"
            produce(filename)
        end
    end
end

path = "somepathdirectoryhere"

for fname in Task(source(path))
    println(fname)
end
```

I cannot find an example on how to do this with channels.  I've tried creating a global channel and using put! instead of produce with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've given an answer below, but just pointing out that the way you used Task here is wrong, even in the old syntax. Task only takes a single function with no arguments as input (so if you want to call another function which_does_ take arguments, you should have "wrapped" it in an anonymous function).

Comment: Thanks.  Yea, I just copied an example for produce and needed to add the dir source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way. Modify your function to accept a channel argument, and `put!` data in it:

```
function source(dir, chnl)
  filelist = readdir(dir)
  for filename in filelist
    name, ext = splitext(filename)
    if ext == ".jld"
      put!(chnl, filename)  % this blocks until "take!" is used elsewhere
    end
  end
end
```

Then create your task *implicitly* using the `Channel` constructor (which takes a function with a single argument only representing the channel, so we need to wrap the `source` function around an anonymous function):

```
my_channel = Channel( (channel_arg) -> source( pwd(), channel_arg) )
```

Then, either check the channel is still open (i.e. task hasn't finished) and if so take an argument:

```
julia> while isopen( my_channel)
         take!( my_channel) |> println;
       end
no.jld
yes.jld
```

or, use the *channel* itself as an iterator (iterating over Tasks is becoming deprecated, along with the produce / consume functionality)

```
julia> for i in my_channel
         i |> println
       end
no.jld
yes.jld
```

Alternatively you can use `@schedule` with `bind` etc as per the documentation, but it seems like the above is the most straightforward way.