# julian way to do python's yield (and yield from)

Tags: julia

What is julian way to do yield (and yield from) [as python do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)?

Edit: I will try to add small example in python.

Think 4x4 chess board. Find every N moves long path chess king could do. Don't waste memory -> make generator of every path.

if we sign every position with numbers:

```
0  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11
12 13 14 16
```

point 0 has 3 neighbors (1, 4, 5). We could find table for every neighbors for every point:

```py
NEIG = [[1, 4, 5], [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 6, 7], [0, 1, 5, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11], [2, 3, 6, 10, 11], [4, 5, 9, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14], [5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 10, 14, 15], [8, 9, 13], [8, 9, 10, 12, 14], [9, 10, 11, 13, 15], [10, 11, 14]]
```

Recursive function (generator) which enlarge given path from list of points or from generator of (generator of ...) points:

```py
def enlarge(path):
    if isinstance(path, list):
        for i in NEIG[path[-1]]:
            if i not in path:
                yield path[:] + [i]
    else:
        for i in path:
            yield from enlarge(i)
```

Function (generator) which give every path with given length

```py
def paths(length):
    steps = ([i] for i in range(16))  # first steps on every point on board
    for _ in range(length-1):
        nsteps = enlarge(steps)
        steps = nsteps
    yield from steps
```

We could see that there is 905776 paths with length 10:

```py
sum(1 for i in paths(10))
Out[89]: 905776
```

In ipython we could timeit:

```py
%timeit sum(1 for i in paths(10))
1.21 s ± 15.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

My julia implementation is ugly and much more complicated. And it seems to be slower.

Comment: it used to be with task / produce / consume. Now it's changing towards channels: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44987612/4183191 . Having said that, note that julia has a `yield` command too.

Comment: Thanks! But thanks to @gggg I found this [discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pygen-python-style-generators/3451/54) where performance tests are really interesting.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Julia Iterators](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/).

```
struct Fibonacci
    last::Int64
end

function Base.iterate(fibo::Fibonacci)
    return 1, (1, 1, 2) # the first output, and the next iteration state
end

function Base.iterate(fibo::Fibonacci, state)
    i, a, b = state
    if i ≤ fibo.last
        return a, (i + 1, b, a + b) # the output, and the next iteration state
    end
end
```

You can then use it like this:

```
for i in Fibonacci(10)
    print(i, " ")
end
```

Which outputs:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
```

This can result in excellent performance, but it is often a bit verbose, and it's also tricky to decide on what iteration state to use, and how to find the next element given that state. In your chess example, I would avoid this approach, but in other cases it can come in really handy.

Comment: This is the most performant answer here, I'm surprised this isn't up further.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [ResumableFunctions.jl](https://github.com/BenLauwens/ResumableFunctions.jl)

from the README

```
using ResumableFunctions

@resumable function fibonnaci(n::Int) :: Int
  a = 0
  b = 1
  for i in 1:n-1
    @yield a
    a, b = b, a+b
  end
  a
end

for fib in fibonnaci(10)
  println(fib)
end
```

Comment: Cool! :) But is it in [production quality](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-resumablefunctions/5711/7)?

Comment: It probably needs a few people to kick the tires before its "production ready". I found that the iterators it creates didn't support `collect` while writing this response, but it only took me about 30 mins to put in a PR fixing that. https://github.com/BenLauwens/ResumableFunctions.jl/pull/6 But it should be way faster than the comparable python generator.

Comment: Fantastic! :D Did you compare ResumableFunctions and python performance or it is just your opinion?

Comment: It's an educated guess, it should be faster for all the reasons that for loops are often faster in julia than python, eg the compiler know all the types and can make specialized code.

Comment: I added python example to the question. `typeof(fibonnaci(10))` is something like `##745` which probably doesn't help compiler to optimize? Using `(i for i in 1:10)` creates `Base.Generator` which seems to me to be slow (maybe if I mix Generator of Int with Generator of Generator of Generator ...). It is very probably that I am doing something wrong... Maybe some type of hand written coroutines solution is what is needed for good performance? Or what could be julian way?

Comment: I was wrong because this `typeof(fibonnaci(11)) <:ResumableFunctions.FiniteStateMachineIterator` is true!

Comment: That's an interesting test case. It's kind of tricky to write in a type stable way, I'll try again later. One catch with `ResumableFunctions` is that you need to write it like the fibonnaci example, where the last value you want "yielded" is instead returned, otherwise you get the default julia return at end of function behavior, which usually gives you a `nothing`, and that screws up the type stability. Here is an attempt with generators, but the return type depends on the passed value, I'm guessing that is why it is slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157501/discussion-between-gggg-and-liso).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Channels:

```
function fibo(n)
    Channel() do ch
        a, b = 0, 1
        for _ in 1:n
            a, b = b, a + b
            put!(ch, a)
        end
    end
end
```

Use it like this:

```
for val in fibo(10)
    print(val, " ")
end
```

Which outputs:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

To get the `yield from` behavior, you can just use a `for` loop. For example, to get the Fibonacci sequence `r` times:

```
function repeat_fibo(r, n)
    Channel() do ch
        for _ in 1:r
            for val in fibo(n)
                put!(ch, val)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

For more details, see the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/asynchronous-programming/#Communicating-with-Channels).

Note that the ResumableFunctions.jl library has some benchmarks showing that their solution is significantly faster than using Channels (see [@gggg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46894510/38626)). Perhaps Channel performance will improve in future Julia versions.

To get better Channel performance, you should set the channel's element type and the channel's size: for example, use `Channel{Int64}(100)` instead of `Channel()`.

Here's a Julia implementation of your chess problem using Channels:

```py
NEIG = [[1, 4, 5], [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 6, 7], [0, 1, 5, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11], [2, 3, 6, 10, 11],
        [4, 5, 9, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14],
        [5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 10, 14, 15], [8, 9, 13],
        [8, 9, 10, 12, 14], [9, 10, 11, 13, 15], [10, 11, 14]]

function paths(start, length)
    Channel{Vector{Int64}}(100) do ch
        if length == 1
            put!(ch, [start])
        else
            for path in paths(start, length - 1)
                for next_step in NEIG[path[end] + 1]
                    next_step in path || put!(ch, [path; next_step])
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function paths(length)
    Channel{Vector{Int64}}(100) do ch
        for start in 0:15
            for path in paths(start, length)
                put!(ch, path)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You can count all the paths of length 10 much like in Python:

```
sum(1 for _ in paths(10))
```

You can also time it:

```
@time sum(1 for _ in paths(10))
```

On my machine this takes about 4 seconds. There are probably ways to optimize this further, but this does show that Channel performance still has some room for improvement.