# switching produce() with put!()

Tags: julia

i am trying to modify a code that was written in julia 0.4 and one of these modifications is replacing `produce()` with `put!()`but i don't really know how am i suppose to replace it knowing that `put!()`requires `Channel`

i have tried `c=Channel(i); put!(c,v)` but i don't know if it is the right way to replace it in this function below

```
function scan()
        i = 1
        init = 1
        while i > 0
            if i >= init
                @objective(m, Max, x[i])
                res = JuMP.solve(m, suppress_warnings=true)
                if res==:Optimal || res==:Unbounded
                    ub[i] = round(Int, getvalue(x[i]))
                    setobjectivesense(m, :Min)
                    res = JuMP.solve(m, suppress_warnings=true)
                    @assert res==:Optimal || res==:Unbounded
                    lb[i] = round(Int, getvalue(x[i]))

                    v[i] = lb[i]
                    init += 1
                else
                    @assert res==:Infeasible
                    i -= 1
                    continue
                end
            elseif v[i] < ub[i]
                v[i] += 1
            else
                setupperbound(x[i], Inf)
                setlowerbound(x[i], -Inf)
                init -= 1
                i -= 1
                continue
            end

            if i >= level
                produce(v)     # the line to be replaced 
                continue
            else
                setupperbound(x[i], v[i])
                setlowerbound(x[i], v[i])
                i += 1
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: What is the code trying to do? That info will make rewriting much easier.

Comment: Somewhere in the code there should have been a `consume` statement that matches to the `produce` statement that you show.  Some of the information in this answer https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-replace-consume-and-produce-with-channels/5125/9 may be of use.

Comment: I don't have time to look at this in detail right now, here's a similar question I answered in the past, where I translated old 'produce' code to the equivalent 'channel' code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44987612/4183191   (Disclaimer: this is an old answer; even though it's channel based, judging by julia's rate of deprecation between versions it's likely deprecated code by now as well, I haven't checked. But hopefully it will lead you in the right direction)

Comment: @OscarSmith it can produce arrays like this for example `v = [-1, 6]
v = [0, 4]
v = [1, 2]`